# Deep Copying const pointer to const Object

Tags: c++, pointers, constants, copy-constructor, deep-copy

I have an object constructor that takes in a const pointer to a const object

```
A::A( const B* const ex): m_B(B){};
```

where m_B:

```
const B* const m_B;
```

I am now trying to create a copy constructor and assignment operator 
I have tried the following without any luck.

Copy Constructor:

```
A::A( const A& cpy): *m_B(*cpy.m_B) {}
```

This does not work...how do I approach this?
Assignment Operator:

```
A& A::operator=(const A& rhs) {

 *m_B = *rhs.m_B // I know this won't work because const cannot be assigned 
                 // error: assignment of read-only data-member
}
```

Any ideas how to solve this problem?

Comment: A copy-constructor is like any other constructor, and doesn't return a value. Also, `operator()` is not assignment, did you copy/paste wrong?

Comment: Sorry massive typos there. Problem still holds

Comment: Your code makes no sense (still copy/paste mistakes). Please try to create a complete, self-contained example. Also, what exactly does not work with your first approach?

Comment: Is `m_B` also `const B* const`? Or is it a simple `const B*`?

Comment: As with most amateur uses of raw pointers, the problem is ill-defined. The fundamental grievance about raw pointers is that they do not convey who is *responsible* for the pointee. Since you do not specify this, it's impossible to give a watertight answer. The only good advice is "don't use raw pointers".

Comment: Then you won't be able to have an assignment operator.

Answer (score 2):

If you want deep copies anyways, why do you have a pointer? Just have a raw object.

```
class B{
  // ...
};

class A{
  const B _b;
public:
  A(A const& other)
    : _b(other._b) {}

private:
  // no assignment operator, since const objects can't be reassigned
  A& operator=(A const&); // undefined
};
```

Comment: Can you every Deep copy a const type from an initialize list. so something like *m_B(*cpy.m_B)  I know this doesn't work, but maybe just my syntax?

Comment: @MWright: With a pointer, you need to allocate new memory `m_B(new B(*other.m_B))`.

Comment: just in the initilization list for const. as I can do a deep copy of a pointer with *ptr_example = *cpy.ptr_example ? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

<s>Your problem is, constructors don't have the return value.</s>

And assignment operator is `operator=`, not `operator()`.

In your constructor, you took a pointer and saved pointer, not the contents of object the pointer points to. If you take this semantics, you should only copy pointers instead of copying the content: (Or do you have something else to achieve?)

```
class B;

class A {
public:
    const B* m_b;
    A( const B* const ex): m_B(ex){};

    //copy constructor
    A(const A& cpy): m_B(cpy.m_B){};
    //assignment operator
    A& operator=(const A&cpy) {m_B = cpy.m_B;};
};
```

Comment: When you initialize m_b you are doing a shallow copy. This is not what I wont as if the copied object goes out of scope I am in trouble. Also is there no way around the assigment operator?

Comment: @fefe: const B* m_B not const B* m_b

Comment: @fefe. I suppose I will only ever need to shallow copy the pointer from the constructor. Thanks, but the assignment operator will still not hold as it is an assignment of a read-only data-member. I think I will make the assignment operator private.

Answer (score 0):

The assignment operator might have to create a new instance with `new`:

```
A& A::operator=(const A& rhs) {
    m_B = new B(rhs.m_B);
    return *this;
}
```

Of course, you have to keep track of this, so you can `delete` the pointer if you allocate it. If you don't want to keep track, use `new` in the constructor as well.

Or even better, use the new [`shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) to not have to care about pointers much at all.

Comment: this != rhs self assignment check also can be added

Comment: @Joachim. The const pointer to B const is already assigned to the heap so I only point to it with m_B. Sorry I did not make this clear at all

Answer (score 0):

The "placement new" operator can be useful when assigning objects that have const pointers.

```
class ref
{
public:
  // Normal constructor creates new immutable reference.
  ref(const char* const ptr, size_t len): m_ptr(ptr),m_len(len) {}
  // Copy constructor creates new copy of existing immutable reference.
  ref(const ref& o): m_ptr(o.m_ptr),m_len(o.m_len) {}
  // Assignment operator replaces existing immutable reference with another one.
  // Previous reference is gone.
  ref& operator=(const ref& o) { new (this) ref(o.m_ptr, o.m_len); return *this; }
private:
  const char* const m_ptr;
  size_t m_len;
}
```